# Get webpage data every 5 seconds and run a given times

Tags: python, web, timer

I want to get the source code of a web page for every 5 seconds, and I want to do it for multiple times. Such as 3 times, then the total time is 3*5 = 15 seconds. I wrote the following code:

```
import urllib2
import threading

def getWebSource(url):
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = usock.read()
    usock.close()

    with open("WebData.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(data)
        myfile.write("\n\n")



url = 'http://www.google.com/'
n = 3
while n>0:
    t = threading.Timer(5.0, getWebSource,args = [url]) # set the seconds here
    t.start()
    n = n-1
```

However, when I run it, what I get is: it only run 5 seconds and read the webpage for 3 times. What is wrong with it? I was expect that it should read the webpage every 5 seconds and repeat it for 3 times.

#### #

Update:Thanks for @wckd , here is my final code:

```
    import urllib2
    import time
    from time import gmtime, strftime

    def getWebSource(url,fout,seconds,times):
        while times > 0:
            usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            data = usock.read()
            usock.close()

            currentTime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
            fout.write(currentTime +"\n")
            fout.write(data)
            fout.write("\n\n")
            times = times - 1
            time.sleep(seconds)



url = 'http://www.google.com'
fout = open("WebData.txt", "a")
seconds = 5
times = 4

getWebSource(url,fout,seconds,times)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method threading.Timer() simply creates a thread that starts after the designated amount of time. While that thread is waiting to run the loop continues to run. Basically you have three threads that all will get run after the 5 seconds.

If you want to have the spacing you could make getWebSource a recursive function with a countdown that will kick off a new thread when it gets run. Or if you want to keep doing what your doing you could multiply the 5 by n to get a spacing. I don't recommend this because if you try for 100 times you'll have 100 threads.

UPDATE

The easiest way to do this in one thread is to add a wait call (also known as sleep) to your loop

```
while n > 0
time.sleep(5)
yourMethodHere()
end
```

However as your method will take time to run keep the thread creation in there and set it to wait 0 seconds.

```
while n > 0
time.sleep(5)
threading.Timer(0, yourMethodHere())
n = n - 1
end
```

This way you won't be confined by a bad connection or something slowing you up.

Comment: Thanks @wckd , your reply is helpful! I am not familiar with the thread stuff. Could you show me how to change the code to make it always run with one thread?

Comment: What I did just now is: add "time.sleep(5)" after the "t.start()". Is this the right method? It run for 15 seconds. But did it has 3 threads run at the same time or now it only have one thread run at one time?

Comment: Cool, seems we got the same idea!

Comment: The way you did it will basically have three threads running at one time. But only three threads. The main thread, the thread running the method, and the thread queued up to run again in 5 seconds. The only further change I would make is to set the timers delay to 0 that will drop you down to two threads which is good for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't know if you care about posting the url but if that's private data you may want to just hide it in the code you posted

Comment: How about my final code posted in the problem update?

Comment: That will work perfectly for one thread. The only issue you have is that it will pull from the webpage and wait 5 seconds. If their is a connection problem you could end up with stats that aren't necessarily at 5 second intervals. i.e. 5 seconds wait 3 seconds run 5 seconds wait 4 seconds run, the difference between them is ~ 7 seconds not the five that you may want.

Comment: yeah, your opinion is totally right! But seems I cannot achieve the original objection.